# How to send intent from a fragment to a service without restarting the service

Tags: android, android-intent, service

I have service and a fragment. Fragment starts the service and after a few moments I want call a method on the service without restarting the service. How to do so?

Comment: You can use LocalBroadcastManager API to achieve your scenario. https://blog.mindorks.com/using-localbroadcastmanager-in-android

Comment: Is there a way to call a method on a fragment from a running service without creating the object the fragment?

Comment: Is the service is running and is your fragment visible at the same time?

Comment: Btw LocalBroadcastManager is deprecated.

Comment: I basically have a countdown timer running on the service and I want to call the methods from the fragment and get their values.

Comment: In that case, you can expose Livedata from your Service class to Fragment class.

Comment: have a look at my answer, let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: You can use Bound services. Refer this : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services

Comment: This is not a good architecture. `Fragment`s come and go more or less at the Andoird framework's whim. Your `Fragment` shouldn't have any data in it that isn't already available to the `Service` some other way. If the `Fragment` is changing data, it should constantly persist that data in the `Service` or somewhere where the `Service` has access to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can expose `Livedata` from your `Service` class to the `Fragment` class.

In your `Service` class, you will have a class instance of `LiveData` property like this (the code below is in `Kotlin`):

```
class MyService : Service() {
    companion object {
        private val _events = MutableLiveData<PUT YOUR VALUE HERE>()
        val events : LiveData<PUT YOUR VALUE HERE> = _events
    }

    // somewhere in service's method, change the value of _events
    _events.postValue( /* post your value here */ )
}
```

**Note :** For `Java`, you can have a static property for both `_events` and `events` from the above code.

In your `Fragment` class, access the `events` property from `Service`

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    // somewhere in your fragment's method, access the _events of MyService
    MyService.events.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,  Observer { yourValue ->
           // do something with your value
    })
}
```

For reference, check this [link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/implementing-an-event-bus-with-livedata--cms-29908).